# uWSGI app with workers communicating over zeromq

Tags: python, flask, ipc, zeromq, uwsgi

I have a Flask application that communicates with a backend worker process over zeromq.

- Using the Flask toy server works.
- Deploying to uWSGI using a single web process is fine.
- Deploying to uWSGI using multiple web processes during setup phase, including communication from all the web processes to the backend worker, is fine.
- Having uWSGI processes communicate to the backend worker during request context **doesn't** work.

So what's the problem? As soon as there is any communication going to the backend worker, zeromq aborts with an EINTR signal. This happens repeatedly and consistently - when trying to send or receive 10 times in a row, it will abort 10 times.

I can't find much documentation in uWSGI with respect to IPC. Do I need to do this by creating a zeromq plugin? On the following page there seems to be a hint, but I can't figure out whether this is what I need or how to use it: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Changelog-1.9.21.html?highlight=zmq_init.

So let me rephrase my question:

- How would you do IPC out of a uWSGI webapp?
- Do you have any idea on what went wrong here, as in what kind of signals zeromq is getting when uWSGI runs in multi process mode?

Here's some code to give you an idea.

**environment.py**

```
class Environment(Flask):

def __init__(self, db_server_uri=u'http://localhost:5984/', debug=True):
    Flask.__init__(self, __name__, static_folder='static')
    self.config.from_object(__name__)
    self.debug = debug
    if debug:
        print "STARTING ENVIRONMENT IN DEBUG MODE"
    self.secret_key = '...'
    self.card_service = CardService(environment_for_logging=self)
    # (...some communication with card service during setup phase, working fine... )
    # (...some stuff happens during request that will call self.card_service.do_some_stuff() ...)
```

**card_service.py**

```
from card_worker import host, work_ports, result_port
class CardService(object):
        def __init__(self, environment_for_logging=None):
            self.environment_for_logging = None
            if environment_for_logging != None:
                self.environment_for_logging = weakref.ref(environment_for_logging)
            context = zmq.Context()
            self.work_sender = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
            port_selected = None
            try:
                #we choose a random port out of four ports since four uwsgi processes will be started
                port_selected = self.work_sender.bind_to_random_port(
                    'tcp://*',
                    min_port=work_ports[0],
                    max_port=work_ports[len(work_ports)-1],
                    max_tries=1000
                )
            except zmq.error.ZMQError as e:
                self.tear_down()
                raise Exception(str(e) + ": " + str(work_uri))
            self.result_receiver = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
            result_uri = "%s:%s" %(host, str(result_port))
            try:
                self.result_receiver.connect(result_uri)
                self.result_receiver.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'')
                if self.environment_for_logging != None and self.environment_for_logging().debug:
                    print "CARDSERVICE IS CONNECTED TO RESULT SOCKET %s" %(result_uri)
            except zmq.error.ZMQError as e:
                self.tear_down()
                raise Exception(str(e) + ": " + str(result_uri))
            if self.environment_for_logging != None and self.environment_for_logging().debug:
                print "CARDSERVICE STARTED ON PORT %s" %(str(port_selected))**

     def _get_result(self, work):
        if self.environment_for_logging != None and self.environment_for_logging().debug:
            print "%s requested from card service" %(work['action'])
        work['work_id'] = str(uuid.uuid4())
        finished = False
        num_trials = 0
        while not finished and num_trials < 10:
            try:
                self.work_sender.send_json(work)
                finished = True
            except zmq.error.ZMQError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EINTR:
                    if self.environment_for_logging != None and self.environment_for_logging().debug:
                        print "zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting"
                    num_trials += 1
                else:
                    raise e
            except TypeError as e:
                raise Exception(str(e) + "; Attempted work package to be serialized: " + pprint.pformat(work))
        result = {}
        finished = False
        num_trials = 0
        while not finished and num_trials < 10:
            try:
                result = self.result_receiver.recv_json() # result_queue.get(block=True,timeout=3)
                if result.get('work_id') != work['work_id']:
                    if self.environment_for_logging != None and self.environment_for_logging().debug:
                        print "card service has received result with the wrong work id: %s" %(result.get('work_id'))
                    continue
                finished = True
            except zmq.error.ZMQError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EINTR:
                    if self.environment_for_logging != None and self.environment_for_logging().debug:
                        print "zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting"
                    num_trials += 1
                else:
                    raise e
        if not finished:
            raise Exception("Data processing could not complete after %i tries" %(num_trials))
        if self.environment_for_logging != None and self.environment_for_logging().debug:
            print "%s finished" %(work['action'])
        return result

      def do_some_stuff(self, input):
        result = self._get_result({
            'action':'do_some_stuff',
            'input':input
        })
        return
```

**card_worker.py** (running in a background process)

```
host = "tcp://127.0.0.1"
work_ports = [6556, 6557, 6558, 6559]
result_port = 7000

class CardWorker(object):
    def __init__(self, debug=True):
        context = zmq.Context()
        self.receiver = context.socket(zmq.PULL)
        for port in work_ports:
            work_uri = "%s:%s" %(host, str(port))
            try:
                self.receiver.connect(work_uri)
                if debug:
                    print "CARD WORKER CONNECTED TO WORK SOCKET %s" %(work_uri)
            except zmq.error.ZMQError as e:
                self.tear_down()
                raise Exception(str(e) + ": " + str(work_uri))

        self.sender = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
        result_uri = "%s:%s" %(host, str(result_port))
        try:
            self.sender.bind(result_uri)
            if debug:
                print "CARD WORKER HAS ESTABLISHED RESULT SOCKET %s" %(result_uri)
        except zmq.error.ZMQError as e:
            self.tear_down()
            raise Exception(str(e) + ": " + str(result_uri))
        self.debug = debug

    def __del__(self):
        os.chdir(self.saved_path)

    def start(self):
        if self.debug:
            print u"LISTENING"
        while True:
            work = self.receiver.recv_json()
            input = work.get('input')
            action = work.get('action')
            work_id = work.get('work_id', '')

            if action == 'do_some_stuff':
                result = {
                    'output':input[0] + input[1]
                }
            result['work_id'] = work_id

            if self.debug:
                print u"SENT:\n" + pprint.pformat(result)
            self.sender.send_json(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-v", "--debug", action="store_true", dest="debug")
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    worker = CardWorker(options.debug)
    worker.start()
```

The result: when calling do_some_stuff within request context, it will just print out "zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting" 10 times. This even happens when stepping through with a debugger. calling uwsgi with `strace -f` doesn't show anything, it just prints

```
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
[pid    71] write(1, "zmq_term interrupted by signal, "..., 43zmq_term interrupted by signal, restarting) = 43
```

in other words I don't see what signal might have caused this behavior. uwsgi is called as follows:

```
uwsgi --http :5000 --module server --callable env --enable-threads --master --processes 4 --honour-stdin --reload-mercy 60
```

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: zeromq Context must be initialized for each worker/process (zeromq magic happens using a pthread). You could add --lazy-apps to reinitialize the app after each fork, or just create the context in a uWSGI @postfork hook/decorator

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your help. I see. So uWSGI forks *after* the Flask app ('environment' in this case) is initialized?

Comment: Nevermind, I've found the documentation on the forking behavior: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html. With lazy-apps it does indeed work. Thanks again!

Comment: I have to say that I ran into troubles later on with this setup and I abandoned the idea to enable concurrency using this method for now - however this has more to do with how the application setup works for my usecase than with the code shown above. Basically, the forking would need to come before anything is initialized instead of somewhere in between. Since I run everything inside docker containers, I can get concurrency also by spawning multiple containers and thus getting the kind of fork I need. Since I can't test above setup for now I don't feel certain enough to create an answer.

Comment: @roberto Your comment should really have been an answer mate! Wish I could give you an upvote for this. Being new to uwsgi itself, I had almost broken my head on a wall trying to figure out why my processes were able to communicate otherwise, but not under uwsgi. Thanks a ton for your comment, lazy initialization was what was needed!